# map() method works to multiple textfiles in Scala spark intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I want to make some operations at text which I read it from multiple textfile, but the map() method takes every file Separately. As example I do:

```
    val text = sc.wholeTextFiles("src/folder").map(a => a._2)
      .flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_)
```

and the result is:

> (hi , 1) //from the first file

> (hi , 1) // from the second file

I want the result to be: (hi,2)

I'm thinking in for loop, but it's does not seem flexibility because I don't know the number of text files

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in spark-shell and these are my findings:
I have 2 files:
csv1 -> hi
csv2 -> hi hi hi

The result was ok after I removed the **end lines**:

```
val text = sc.wholeTextFiles("testSO/").map(a => a._2).flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(line => line.replace("\n","")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(hi,4)
```

This was the result without removing endlines:

```
scala> val text = sc.wholeTextFiles("testSO/").map(a => a._2).flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
(hi,2)
(hi
,2)
```

Comment: it still the same with me. but I'm using a text file not csv

Comment: maybe you can give me an input example so i can test it out

Comment: like: doc1.txt -> blue, doc2.text-> blue blue .
Thanks.

Comment: `scala> val text = sc.wholeTextFiles("/testBlue/").map(a => a._2).flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(line => line.replace("\n","")).map(word => (word,1)).reduceByKey(_+_).foreach(println)`
Output: `(blue,3)`